# Get a boolean value back from `array_filter` if the array has been filtered

Tags: php

Im using PHP 8.2 to filter an array, I would also like a value boolean value returned if the array has actually been filtered based on my condition.

For example, I have:

```
$array = [...];

$filteredArray = array_filter($arr, function ($arr) {
    return in_array($array['Type'], ['A', 'CNAME']);
});

$hasBeenFiltered = count(array_diff($array, $filteredArray)) > 0;;
```

However this looks quite messy, are there any better ways to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the arrays differ in their length, then something must have been removed:

```
$hasBeenFiltered = count($filteredArray) < count($array);
```

Comment: Additionally, [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) keeps original keys (this is documented explicitly so it can be relied on), which allows to figure out _which_ elements have been filtered out, should you ever need it.